# Exploit a backup program using C

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

I'm doing an assignment of a security course that asks me to find 4 vulnerabilities of a backup program (setuid) and use each of them to gain root access (on a virtual linux machine with old version of gcc etc.).
There should be one of buffer overflow and one of format string.

Could anyone help me to point out where the 4 vulnerabilities are?
I think the buffer overflow can happened in `copyFile()`.

The following is the code for backup.c: (which can be invoked in "backup backup foo" or "backup restore foo")

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define CMD_BACKUP 0
#define CMD_RESTORE 1

#define BACKUP_DIRECTORY "/usr/share/backup"
#define FORBIDDEN_DIRECTORY "/etc"

static
int copyFile(char* src, char* dst)
{
  char buffer[3072]; /* 3K ought to be enough for anyone*/
  unsigned int i, len;
  FILE *source, *dest;
  int c;

  source = fopen(src, "r");
  if (source == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open source file\n");
    return -1;
  }

  i = 0;
  c = fgetc(source);
  while (c != EOF) {
    buffer[i]  = (unsigned char) c;
    c = fgetc(source);
    i++;
  }

  len = i;
  fclose(source);

  dest = fopen(dst, "w");
  if (dest == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open destination file\n");
    return -1;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    fputc(buffer[i], dest);

  fclose(dest);

  return 0;
}

static
int restorePermissions(char* target)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int status;
  char *user, *userid, *ptr;
  FILE *file;
  char buffer[64];
  mode_t mode;

  // execute "chown" to assign file ownership to user
  pid = fork();

  // error
  if (pid < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // parent
  if (pid > 0) {
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    if (WIFEXITED(status) == 0 || WEXITSTATUS(status) < 0)
      return -1;
  }
  else {

    // child
    // retrieve username
    user = getenv("USER");
    // retrieve corresponding userid   
    file = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open password file\n");
      return -1;
    }
    userid = NULL;
    while (!feof(file)) {
      if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
    ptr = strtok(buffer, ":");
    if (strcmp(ptr, user) == 0) {
      strtok(NULL, ":"); // password
      userid = strtok(NULL, ":"); // userid
      ptr = strtok(NULL, ":"); // group
      *ptr = '\0';
      break;
    }
      }
    }

    if (userid != NULL) 
      execlp("/bin/chown", "/bin/chown", userid, target, NULL);

    // reached only in case of error
    return -1;
  }  

  mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IEXEC;
  chmod(target, mode);

  return 0;
}

static
void usage(char* parameter) 
{
  char newline = '\n';
  char output[96];
  char buffer[96];

  snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
        "Usage: %.60s backup|restore pathname%c", parameter, newline);

  sprintf(output, buffer);
  printf(output);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  int cmd;
  char *path, *ptr;
  char *forbidden = FORBIDDEN_DIRECTORY;
  char *src, *dst, *buffer;
  struct stat buf;

  if (argc != 3) {
    usage(argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  if (strcmp("backup", argv[1]) == 0) {
    cmd = CMD_BACKUP;
  }
  else if (strcmp("restore", argv[1]) == 0) {
    cmd = CMD_RESTORE;
  } else {
    usage(argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  path = argv[2];

  // prevent access to forbidden directory
  ptr = realpath(path, NULL);
  if (ptr != NULL && strstr(ptr, forbidden) == ptr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Not allowed to access target/source %s\n", path);
    return 1;
  }

  // set up paths for copy operation
  buffer = malloc(strlen(BACKUP_DIRECTORY) + 1 + strlen(path) + 1);
  if (buffer == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (cmd == CMD_BACKUP) {
    src = path;

    dst = buffer;
    strcpy(dst, BACKUP_DIRECTORY);
    strcat(dst, "/");
    strcat(dst, path);
  }
  else {
    src = buffer;
    strcpy(src, BACKUP_DIRECTORY);
    strcat(src, "/");
    strcat(src, path);

    dst = path;

    // don't overwrite existing file if we don't own it
    if (stat(dst, &buf) == 0 && buf.st_uid != getuid()) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Not your file: %s\n", dst);
      return 1;
    }
  }

  // perform actual backup/restore operation
  if (copyFile(src, dst) < 0)
    return 1;

  // grant user access to restored file
  if (cmd == CMD_RESTORE) {
    if (restorePermissions(path) < 0)
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And something useful:

```
  // one way to invoke backup
  //system("/usr/local/bin/backup backup foo");

  // another way
  args[0] = TARGET; args[1] = "backup"; 
  args[2] = "foo"; args[3] = NULL;

  env[0] = NULL;
  if (execve(TARGET, args, env) < 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "execve failed.\n");
  exit(0);
```

Comment: Why are you asking other people to do your homework for you?  This looks suspiciously like cheating.

Comment: I'm not asking how to write the code but just try to get some idea. I don't have much experience on low level C programming. So hopefully I can get some help.

Comment: What is the directory structure under `/usr/share/backup/` ?

Comment: Sorry for the late relpy. It's a empty directory but can be accessed by root only (I cracked it on one vulnerability and saw this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The format vulnerability is in `usage()` - with the `sprintf()` and `printf()` taking format strings that are generated from `argv[0]`, which an attacker can manipulate to contain whatever they want.
2. The main buffer overflow is the one highlighted by [Péter Török](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265143/peter-torok); when scanning code for security vulnerabilities, any unchecked buffer filling with blatant comments like that is a signpost asking for trouble.
3. The environment variable USER is used - it could be manipulated by the unscrupulous, but it is debatable whether it would really buy you anything.  You could set it to say 'root', and the attempted 'chown' command would user the name it was told to use.
4. There's a race of sorts between the `chown` command and the `chmod()` system call.  It isn't immediately clear how you'd exploit that separately from the other issues - but it might give you something to leverage.

Including `<sys/types.h>` twice is redundant but otherwise harmless.  With POSIX 2008, it isn't even needed in most places at all.

Comment: The "forbidden" directory is also inadequate - you could use this program to place a trojan `ls` command into `/sbin`, which usually appears in root's path before `/bin`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I don't get the 4th point. I'm a noob on system call. Do you mean I can use chown to reset the mode in chmod?

Comment: Also thanks to caf. But I don't get how can you use "ls" to modify the  "forbidden" directory.

Comment: @Chris: the point @caf was making is that ensuring that the user does not write to /etc is not sufficient; the user should not write to /sbin (or /bin or /usr/bin or /lib or /usr/lib or /usr/sbin, to name but a few critical places).

Comment: @Chris: my point 4 is that it is not defined whether the chmod or the chown operation will succeed first - the relative timing of the child and the parent is not clear.  That might leave a period of time while the file is modifiable outside of this program and it shouldn't be.  It is a small risk; as I said, I'm not immediately sure how I'd leverage it.  However, in conjunction with things like FIFOs, which block if you open them for reading and there is no writer, or broken symlinks, or various other devious gadgets, there might be some chance to do something.

Comment: @Chris: also, S_IEXEC is a non-standard term; I suspect it is equivalent to S_IXUSR|S_IXGRP|S_IXOTH.  Generally, making files executable by default is a bad idea.

Comment: @Chris: incidentally, the problem with the buffer overflow occurs if the file to be copied is bigger than 3K - any of your MP3 files should kill your program nicely.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I think the attack scenario for 4 would be: program  checks dest file can be restored into your home dir, you create a hard link to something sensitive, program overwrites something sensitive. Just do it `while [true]`.

Comment: @ninjalj: something along those general lines sounds about right, yes.

Comment: I got it. But point 4 looks really hard to implement. And the same as environment variable "USER". Even if you can use it to change the owner of the backup file to root, how can you run the file?

Comment: @Chris: I think 4 is hard to exploit.  OTOH, you can set USER to any value you like, so you can create a file for any user you choose, whether or not they wanted you to be able to do so.  How much that matters isn't so clear.  You have a file which is owned by someone else with 711 permission - you can execute it, but it isn't itself setuid; you can delete it if you can write in the directory; but I'm not sure whether that's enough.  It isn't good, though, to be able to get a file owned by someone else, though.

Answer (score 5):

I am not a security expert, but the comment here

```
char buffer[3072]; /* 3K ought to be enough for anyone*/
```

is telling :-) So as you have guessed, there is a possibility for buffer overflow here. The buffer is in fact used to read the contents of the input file in. So try it with a file longer than 3K.

Now, since `buffer` is local, it is allocated on the stack. Thus by overflowing, you can overwrite the contents of the stack, including the return address and local variables within the caller stack frame. This is the theory as far as I know, I can't give you any more practical details though.

Comment: Thanks. Like I mentioned I used the code from "exploit3.c" and set argv[1] to 3172, which not work. And I also tried a lot of other values but most cause segmentation fault or illegal instruction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to use the return address to jump to my shell code, but how to find the right position looks really hard, even with NOPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exploit buffer-overflows on Linux anymore, since SE-Linux prevents malicious or accidental unintended code execution by aborting the program in question, and by Wand-addresss randomization.

You need to switch off those programms first, but that requires root access in the first place.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I have updated the environment is a virtual machine which should be an old version of linux I think.

Comment: @wich: True, but it's ON-BY-DEFAULT on Fedora. And I certainly use it, after all I know why. It disabled one of my selfmade aimbots once.

Comment: there's more to linux than Fedora

Comment: @wich: I know that, but Ubuntu is also rolling it, however, it's the easier (but not so good) SE Linux replacement. And I also know that there's more to Linux than Fedora + Ubuntu/Debian (in theory) ;-)) But what's in Fedora today, will be in RHEL&CentOS soon, which means SuSe will just take it from there, once it is mature.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by vulnerability 4 on Jonathan Leffler's answer, here is an exploit for a TOCTOU (race condition in the interval from Time Of Check to Time of Update of a file) between the `realpath()` check and `fopen()`

```
trap 'rm -f my_passwd; kill -TERM 0' INT

function p1()
{
    while [[ 1 ]]
    do
            nice -20 ./backup restore my_passwd
            ls -l /etc/passwd /etc/my_passwd my_passwd
    done
}

function p2()
{
    while [[ 1 ]]
    do
            rm -f my_passwd; ln /etc/my_passwd my_passwd; sleep .1; rm -f my_passwd
    done
}

export USER=root
p1 & p2
```

Anyway, setting your `UMASK` to `000` should allow similar exploitation for the `chmod()` issue.

Comment: This is really awesome. I'm trying to do similar things in c.

Answer (score -1):

Also think about whether a string comparison is enough to lock out the forbidden directory.    Answer:  No, in at least two ways I can think of.